# Most elementary proof showing that exponential growth wins against polynomial growth

Tags: inequalities

This question is motivated by teaching : I would like to see a completely elementary proof showing for example that for all natural integers $k$ we have eventually $2^n>n^k$.

All proofs I know rely somehow on properties of the logarithm.
(I have nothing against logarithms but some students loathe them.)

*Is there a brilliant "proof from the book" for this inequality
(for example given by an explicit easy injection of a set
containing $n^k$ elements into, say, the set of subsets of $\lbrace 1,\ldots,n\rbrace$ for $n$ sufficiently large)?*

A fairly easy but somewhat computational proof (which leaves me therefore unhappy):

Given $k$ choose $n_0>2^{k+1}$. For $n>n_0$ we have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{(n+1)^k}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n^k}{2^n}+\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{k\choose j}n^j}{2^n}\right)\\
&\leq \frac{n^k}{2^n}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2^k}{2n_0}\right)\\
\leq \frac{3}{4}\frac{n^k}{2^n}
\end{align*}
showing that the ratio $\frac{n^k}{2^n}$ decays exponentially fast for $n>n_0$.

A perhaps more elementary but slightly sloppy proof is the observation that digits of $n\longmapsto 2^{2^n}$ (roughly) double when increasing $n$ by $1$ whilst digits of $n\longmapsto (2^n)^k$
form (roughly) an arithmetic progression. (And this "proof" uses therefore properties of the logarithm in disguise.)

**Addendum:** Fedor Petrov's proof can be slightly rewritten as
$$2^{n+k}=\sum_j{n+k\choose j}>{n+k\choose k+1}>n^k\frac{n}{(k+1)!}$$
showing
$$2^n>n^k\frac{n}{2^k(k+1)!}>n^k$$
for $n>2^k(k+1)!$.

**Second addendum:** Here is sort of an
"injective" proof: $n^{k+1}$ is the number of sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{k+1})\in \lbrace 1,2,\ldots,n\rbrace^{k+1}$. Writing down the corresponding binary expressions, adding leading zeroes in order to make them of equal length $l\leq n$ (with $l$ such that $n<2^l$) and concatenating them we get
a binary representation of an integer $<2^{l(k+1)}\leq 2^{n(k+1)}$ which encodes $(a_1,\ldots,a_{k+1})$ uniquely. This shows
$$2^{(k+1)n}>n^{k+1}.$$
Replacing $(k+1)n$ by $N$ we get
$$2^N>N^k\frac{N}{(k+1)^{k+1}}>N^k$$
for $N$ in $(k+1)\mathbb N$ such that  $N>(k+1)^{k+1}$.

For the general case we have
$$2^{N-a}>N^k\frac{N}{2^a(k+1)^{k+1}}>(N-a)^k\frac{N-a}{2^a(k+1)^{k+1}}>(N-a)^k$$
(where $a$ is in $\lbrace 0,1,\ldots,k\rbrace$) if $N-a>2^k(k+1)^{k+1}$.

*Variation for the last proof:* One can replace binary representations by characteristic functions: $a_i$ is encoded by the $a_i$-th basis vector of $\mathbb R^n$. Concatenating coefficients of these $k+1$ basis vectors we get a subset (consisting of $k+1$ elements) of $\lbrace 1,\ldots,(k+1)n\rbrace$.

Comment: At this point I think all who have responded except me have missed an important point.

Comment: The combinatorial proof is nice! But as it is only covers large N that are multiples of k+1… Is there a variation of the argument that directly covers all large n?

Comment: @PietroMajer : I have added the general case.

Comment: I can solve SAT in $O(2^n)$ operations, but I'm not a millionaire. It follows that $2^n \gg n^k$.

Comment: In your addendum, if presenting this to students, I would insert an extra step: namely ${n+k\choose k +1}=(n+k)\cdots(n+1)\frac{n!}{(k+1)!}$ and then the last inequality.

Comment: Here's a simple injection of $[n]^2$ into $2^{[n]}$ for $n \geq 8$: For an ordered pair $(a,b)$ take either $\{a,a+1,a+2,\dotsc,b\}$ or $\{b,b+1,\dotsc,a\}$ (modulo $n$), whichever is smaller; if $a \leq b$ leave it at that, otherwise throw in one more element in the middle of the omitted interval (say, $b+2$ in the first case, $a+2$ in the second case). For example for $n=8$, $(3,5) \mapsto \{3,4,5\}$, $(5,3) \mapsto \{3,4,5,7\}$, $(7,1) \mapsto \{7,0,1,3\}$.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are looking for something to teach with in the future, or just asking a question that happened to be inspired by a teaching experience?

Comment: I added a simple argument showing that $2^{n/k}>\max(16,k^2)$ implies $2^{n/k}>n$.

Comment: *"(I have nothing against logarithms but some students loathe them.)"* Unfortunately, many teachers introduce logarithm as "Here is one more boring abstract function whose properties you need to know by heart". So it's not a surprise that many students end up loathing logarithms. Perhaps if logarithm was introduced as "this awesome function that morphs hard multiplication into easy addition" then it would receive a bit more love.

Comment: @Stef :  You are absolutely right. I would consider introducing logarithms in arithmetic rather than in algebra (and for that matter, I think most postsecondary students would benefit from a conceptual rather than technical course in arithmetic). But in another forum, when I mentioned this, I was startled to find more than one person who thought that what I meant was that I would introduce the use of logarithm tables to change multiplication to addition. Sometimes I'm amazed that mathematicians can be so dumb when topics like this come up. (I would probably introduce that$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$way of using tables if plenty of time were available, after covering more important and basic stuff.) $\qquad$

Comment: What sort of students do you have in mind presenting this to? You say some students loath logarithms. That suggests they're not learning what polynomial and exponential functions are for the first time. And yet it as when I first learned what polynomial and exponential functions were that I figured out the answer to the question posed here, and I certainly wouldn't have known anything about how to use logarithms in so doing at that time, nor any of the various techniques proposed by you and by others posting here, other than myself. It seems to me that that earlier$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$stage of learning is the natural place for this question to be addressed.

Comment: $\ldots\,$but none of the answers posted here except mine are suitable for that earlier stage of learning.

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon: Your proof is clearly the best one here, but it only shows that $\limsup 2^n/n^k=\infty$.

Comment: If the students are already happy with the Dold-Kan correspondence (which I like to do pretty early on), an easy argument goes like this: any simplicial set whose simplex count in dim n is bounded by a polynomial of degree k has homology supported in degrees <= k (using Dold-Kan); so $B\mathbb{Z}/2$, which has homology in all degrees, cannot be bounded by any polynomial. Students generally like using Stiefel-Whitney classes because they feel so familiar (even if learning the binomial theorem might serve them better in the long run...)

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon This feels to me a bit like using aircraft carriers for killing flies!

Comment: @Roland, I don't see how one would use an aircraft carrier to kill a fly. Wouldn't the fly just fly up, out of the reach of the ship?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Assume that $n>k$. Then
$$2^n=\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j}>{n\choose k+1}=n^k\left(\frac{n}{(k+1)!}+O(1)\right).$$

Comment: @GHfromMO not that I am against this editing, but strictly speaking, $O(1)$ makes sense only for large enough $n$, so $n>k$ assumption is not necessary (and also this specific inequality is never used: for smaller $n$ the bound also holds, trivially).

Comment: You are right, the assumption $n>k$ is not needed for the inequality $2^n>{n\choose k+1}$, because for $n\leq k$ the right-hand side is zero. Feel free to revert to the earlier version. On the other hand, I disagree with you concerning $O(1)$: this symbol means any bounded function of the variables involved, without any restriction on the variables. In the current context, $O(1)$ means any bounded function of $n$ (for any fixed $k$). Of course $n$ is a positive integer, so being bounded for all $n$ is equivalent to being bounded for all $n>n_0(k)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO hm, if we allow infinite values, can we say $1/\log n =O(1)$? I would say yes, because $O$ and $o$ are about asumptotic properties, not global properties. (If the values are finite a priori, and the domain of a function is "positive integers", than being bounded is the same as "being bounded for large $n$", but it seems to be rather a coincidence).

Comment: The symbol $1/\log n$ assumes that $n$ is positive. If $n$ is a positive integer, then $1/\log n=O(1)$. If $n$ is a positive real number, then $1/\log n\neq O(1)$. To me, $O(1)$ is not about asymptotic properties. Instead, $O(1)$ simply means a bounded quantity, unlike the $o(1)$ notation which assumes a limit situation such as $n\to\infty$. Of course there are variations of the $O(1)$ notation. For example, "$1/\log n=O(1)$ as $n\to\infty$",means that $1/\log n$ is bounded for $n$ sufficiently large, but I don't like this variation (e.g. because $n\to\infty$ is different from $n\geq n_0$).

Comment: @GHfromMO: for what it's worth, the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) does not support your conventions about the meaning of $O(1)$.

Comment: "If $n$ is a positive integer, then $1/\log n=O(1)$" - But $1/\log n$ is not bounded at $n=1$. If you mean that this point should be ignored, then it is the same agreement that we must care only about  large enough $n$.

Comment: @SamHopkins The Wikipedia page talks about "$f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to\infty$". Then it mentions that "In many contexts, the assumption that we are interested in the growth rate as the variable $x$ goes to infinity is left unstated, and one writes more simply that $f(x)=O(g(x))$." At any rate, there are different schools and priorities. In my field, $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means that $|f(x)|\leq Mg(x)$ for all $x$ and a suitable constant $M>0$.

Comment: The expression $1/\log n$ is undefined at $n=1$. We don't divide by zero. You are right, I was a bit sloppy, and I should have said that $1/\log n=O(1)$ for integers $n\geq 2$. My point is that any limit situation only contaminates the plain and simple $O(1)$ notation. One can emphasize "for $n$ sufficiently large" or "for $x$ sufficiently close to $x_0$" if needed. See also my previous remark (meant for Sam Hopkins). At any rate, we talked too much about this topic.

Comment: @SamHopkins I should add that Wikipedia (and you and Fedor Petrov) are correct in that originally $f(x)=O(g(x))$ meant $|f(x)|\leq M g(x)$ for $x\geq x_0$. For example, this is the definition used by Landau in his 1909 book on prime numbers. At any rate, in analytic number theory, we often drop the condition $x\geq x_0$, because such a condition (with a fixed but large $x_0$) is already assumed throughout the paper. For example, when we write $\log\log x$, we usually understand that $x$ is so large that this expression exceeds $2$, say.

Comment: @GHfromMO In the domain $k\geq 1$ and $n\geq 1$ given in the problem statement, your $O(1)$ term lies in the interval $(-1/5,1/2]$.  It seems that the $O(1)$ is justifiable even by the Wikipedia definition.

Comment: @2734364041 My remarks did not concern the validity of $O(1)$ if Fedor Petrov's argument. Instead, they concerned what we really mean by $O(1)$, in response to Fedor Petrov's first two comments.

Comment: Taylor's version: $2^n=e^{n\log 2}>\frac{(n\log2)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$.

Comment: This is the right answer, but isn't a bit embarrassing that so many people in MO find it so groundbreaking? Any freshman student is supposed to know that the simplest explanation is via comparison with binomial coefficients.

Comment: @PietroMajer people may have different voting philosophy, +1 does not always assume that the answer is groundbreaking (especially in such matters where it is pretty hard to groundbreak). I find it simply funny that the answers I am really proud of get much less votes than such.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, it's curious... Let's say that in the average it's ok ;)

Comment: @PietroMajer, this beautiful explanation is far from the simplest one. You don't get to just write O(1) and call it a proof at that level of the audience (even assuming they are fluent with binomial theorem).

Comment: @Kostya_I in the version proposed now in OP: $2^{n+k}>{n+k\choose k+1}>n^{k+1}/(k+1)!$ this is possibly the simplest.

Comment: @Kostya_I I thought the inequality version  was as well-known as (a+b)(a-b), that's why I was surprised.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: It is a well established fact that the deeper an answer is, the fewer upvotes it gets (and vice versa). I suppose people rarely upvote an answer they don't understand.

Answer (score 89):

For $n>k+1$, substitute $2n$ for $n$ in both $2^n$ and $n^k$. Note that the first is multiplied by $2^n$ and the second by $2^k$ which is at least twice as small. Therefore applying this enough times will make $2^n$ larger than $n^k$, since both are larger than $0$.

Comment: Or, in a word and a half: "double n".

Comment: A slight variation: when $2^n$ gets multiplied by $2^n$ and $n^k$ gets multiplied by $2^k$, the ratio $2^n/n^k$ gets multiplied by $2^{n-k}$. From this position, I feel like I can follow the Archimedean property more directly to the desired result.

Comment: To me this is by far the most elementary solution, the only one I would feel comfortable explaining the high school students.

Comment: @MiloMoses - I completely agree. In my opinion, this is the proof from "the book". It captures the intuition of the "what happens if you increase n by 1?" argument that so many of the answers try to latch onto, while also being completely self-contained (you don't need to know what a logarithm or even a binomial coefficient is to understand it) and rigorous. And even when written out in words, it's just 2.5 lines wrong. What more could we ever really ask for?

Comment: @NathanielJohnston, the reason this proof is so much shorter than the others is that a weaker result is proven, and details (Therefore...) are omitted.

Comment: @Kostya_I Those details are just [the archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property).

Comment: I mainly agree with Kostya_I: the reason this proof is so short (not necessarily much shorter than all the others) is that a weaker result is proven. Indeed, if $r_n:=2^n/n^k$, then what is proven here is that $r_{2^j}\to\infty$ (as $\mathbb N\ni j\to\infty$), rather than $r_n\to\infty$ (as $\mathbb N\ni n\to\infty$).

Comment: @IosifPinelis All you need "oh, and both are monotonic" to turn the first result into the second, as the $2^j$ "supports" the parts between.

Comment: @Yakk : No, that would not be enough. It is an easy exercise to construct two positive increasing sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that for $r_n:=a_n/b_n$ we have $r_{2^j}\to\infty$ but $r_n\not\to\infty$.

Comment: @Yakk : Specifically, one may let $a_{2^j}=(j!)^2$, $b_{2^j}=((j-1)!)^2 j$, and $a_n=b_n=(j!)^2\log_2n$ if $2^j<n<2^{j+1}$.

Comment: You can start from all real $n$ in $(k+1,2k+2]$

Comment: I do believe that this is an incomplete proof. It seems to assert that if for all fixed $r$ the sequence $a_{2^nr}$ converges to zero, then so does $a_n$. Said this bluntly, it is easy to produce a counterexample (like $a_n=1$ for odd $n$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise). To fix the argument, one has to say what is so special about $a_n=n^k/2^n$ that it still works.  For example, $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing. And this is what is missing in this proof and that makes it so short.

Comment: @MaartenHavinga I don't think that would work so easily. The desired result is the existence of a real number $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $2^n>n^k$. But each value $x$ from your interval $I=(k+1,2k+2]$ will give rise to a different lower bound $n_0=n_0(x)$. You still need to show that the set of all these numbers $n_0(x)$, where $x$ ranges over $I$, has an upper bound.

Comment: but hasn’t  the  argument “for $n=2^j$ the inequality is equivalent to $2^j\ge kj$ “ already appeared in various answers?

Comment: I guess one way to turn this into a rigorous proof is to observe that if $n^k\geq 2^n$ and $(n+1)^k<2^{n+1}$, then $(\frac{n+1}{n})^k < 2$.  It follows that for $m>n$, $(\frac{m+1}{m})^k< 2$, so induction gives $(m+1)^k<2m^k<2(2^m)=2^{m+1}$ for each  $m>n$.  It therefore suffices to find a single $n$ satisfying the inequality.

Comment: @MW The question I was considering is not "can this be turned into a rigorous proof?" but "is this proof elementary and self-contained?"

Answer (score 25):

The cleanest way I can think of is to show that if $p(n)$ is ***any*** polynomial with integer coefficients, then eventually $p(n)<2^n$ for large enough $n$.

##### Proof

The proof is by induction - the degree zero case hopefully being obvious.

Suppose the result holds for degree smaller than $k$, and $p(n)$ has degree $k$.

Then $p(n+1)-p(n)$ has degree strictly less than $k$ (one doesn't even need to get into the full binomial expansion to convince a student of this, just observe that $(n+1)^k=n^k+\dots$, where the remaining terms have degree smaller than $k$.)

Therefore, eventually

$$p(n+1)-p(n)<2^n = 2^{n+1}-2^n,$$
or equivalently,
$$2^n-p(n) < 2^{n+1}- p(n+1).$$

Thus $2^n-p(n)$ is eventually strictly increasing, and hence (as an integral sequence) will eventually become and remain positive, and so the case for degree $k$ is proved.

Comment: my favorite so far!

Answer (score 21):

I think this is an explanation good for a variety of levels. This is in some of the other answers but I'd emphasize that writing it out with discussion at each point can be more clear than some of the computation.

Think of the ratio between consecutive terms in $n^k$: $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^k$.

And compare
$$n^k = \left(\frac{2}{1}\right)^k \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k \cdots \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^k $$
$$2^n = \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdots 2}_{\text{n times}} $$

I think here some students can already imagine the rest of an explanation.

Now, you need to explain that we can find $n_0$ such that $\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^k < 1.5$. (Of course easiest by taking logs :) but I think this is more intuitive than the original fact.)

And then you need to explain that we can write

$$n^k = \left(\frac{2}{1}\right)^k \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k \cdots \left(\frac{n_0}{n_0-1}\right)^k \left(\frac{n_0+1}{n_0}\right)^k \cdots \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^k  $$
$$n^k \leq \underbrace{\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)^k \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k \cdots \left(\frac{n_0}{n_0-1}\right)^k}_{\text{some constant}} \underbrace{\frac{3}{2} \cdots \frac32}_{n-n_0 \text{ times}}  $$

And it comes down to explaining that, if $a > b$ then $C_1 a^n$ eventually beats $C_2 b^n$.

On a board or with some pictures, you can get a lot out of writing the results out in the "$\cdots$" form, since you can put a big square around the terms that we stuff into the "constant" and emphasize that we don't care how big we got up to that point. I like this explanation because I think it's quite open to discussion as you go, and invites some thought from advanced students; like, how does the choice of $3/2$ affect things like the final estimates we get? We're ultimately bounding polynomial growth from above by exponential growth!

Answer (score 11):

The following proof works for any real $k>0$ (the case $k\le0$ is obvious).

For $a:=2^{1/(2k)}-1>0$, we have
$$\frac{2^n}{n^k}=\Big(\frac{(1+a)^n}{n^{1/2}}\Big)^{2k}
\ge\Big(\frac{1+na}{n^{1/2}}\Big)^{2k}
\ge(an^{1/2})^{2k}\to\infty$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 11):

A more visual perspective (not sure about proof) is embedding a tree formed by $n^{k}$ into the binary-tree formed by $2^{n}$.

**For $k=1$**, we have the following picture

[image]
(from "Average Redundancy for Known Sources: Ubiquitous Trees in Source Coding")

Along each diagonal in $Z^{2}_{+}$, we have linear growth 2,3,4,5. Whereas for the binary tree we have 2,4,8,16. So the lattice path has more options in the binary tree.

We see that in $Z^{2}_{+}$, every interior vertex has two-parents eg. (1,1) has parents (1,0) and (0,1). Whereas in the binary-tree every parent has two children vertices.

Every lattice upright path in $Z^{2}_{+}$ has a unique corresponding descending path in the binary-tree. We have a bijection. The number of paths that reach the node $(n,n)$ is exactly $2n$ (we just need more than one). Whereas for the binary tree every node can only be reached by exactly one path. Therefore, we must have fewer nodes on the diagonal connecting $(n,0)$ and $(0,n)$, then we have at the $n$-th level in the binary tree.

You could also ask "Suppose we have two cities A and B, in A every parent can single-produce two children and in B every children must have two parents, which population will grow faster?" i.e. $2^{n}\geq 2n$ for $n\geq 1$.

**For higher $k$**

I think for polynomial $n^k$, we might be able to take $\mathbb{Z}_{+}^{2k}$ (check), because each time we take another Cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}_{+}^{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{+}^{2}\times\dotsb$ we provide another $n$-options. So here the lattice path picks the next vertex uniformly that are 1-edge away. It is unclear if there is a nice correspondence with the binary tree.

Alternatively, we can try to take $\mathbb{Z}^{k+1}$ because we are basically study the number of vertices that are distance $n$ using the metric $|x_{1}|+\dotsb+|x_{k}|=n$. This number grows like $n^{k-1}$ from partition theory [What are the best known bounds on the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct parts?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72418/what-are-the-best-known-bounds-on-the-number-of-partitions-of-n-into-exactly). But this goes beyond elementary.

I am trying to think if there is a natural embedding here that makes it obvious, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you prove $2^n\geq n+1$  (there are (n+1)  possible endpoints for up and right lattice paths of length $n$,  the tree  model keeps track of the whole path). This generalizes easily to $d^n\geq {n+d-1\choose d-1}$. An  algebraic reformulation : There are $d^n$ monomials of total degree $n$  in  $d$ non-commuting variables and there are  only  ${n+d-1\choose d-1}$ such monomials in commuting variables.

Answer (score 7):

Denote $L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^k/2^n$ and consider that
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)^k}{2^{n+1}}=\tfrac{1}{2}L\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/n)^k=\tfrac{1}{2}L\Rightarrow L=0.$$

You can find many more "proofs" at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468/87355

---

update in response to the comments: can $L$ be infinite?

if $L_n\equiv n^k/2^n$, then, $L_{n+1}=\tfrac{1}{2}(1+1/n)^k L_n<L_n$ for suffiently large $n\geq N$;
therefore, $L_n=L_{N}\frac{L_{N+1}}{L_{N}}\frac{L_{N+2}}{L_{N+1}}\cdots \frac{L_{n}}{L_{n-1}}<L_{N}$ for $n>N$.

Comment: This "proof" assumes that the limit $L$ exists, which is not a given.

Comment: I don't see the conclusion here, why can't $L$ even be infinity?

Comment: The update also shows that the $L_n$ are eventually monotonic decreasing (and bounded below by zero) so the limit exists.

Comment: otherwise define $L=\limsup_{n\to\infty}n^k/2^n$, then from  the same computation  $L=L/2$

Comment: Is the edit meant to say that $L_{n+1}/L_N=(1/2)(1+1/n)^k < 1$ for suffiently large $n$? As is the first equalit is incorrect.  And once you're there, havent you basically bounded $L_n$ from above by a decaying geometric series... so the $L=\frac12 L$ trick doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a completely elementary proof, without properties of logarithm, binomial expansion, or limits. On the other hand it's certainly not a proof "from the book"! Back to the first hand, we can compare any increasing exponential, not just $2^n$.

Step 1: Bernoulli's inequality: For all $x>-1$ and all integers $n \geq0$, $(1+x)^n \geq 1 + nx$. This can be proven by very elementary induction.

Step 2: Now, exponentials beat linears: given an exponential function $(1+x)^n$ with $x > 0$ (note: here $x$ is constant, and we regard this as a function of $n$) and given a slope $m$, we have $(1+x)^n > m/x$ for $n$ greater than some $n_0$, and then $(1 + x)^n > (m/x)( 1 + (n-n_0)x)$, which is a linear function of $n$ of slope $m$. We've given up control of the constant term, but we can get it back: the exponential eventually exceeds *some* linear function of slope $m+1$, which in turn eventually exceeds *any* linear function of slope $m$.

Step 3: Now fix $k$. We have in particular $(1 + x)^n > k(n+1)$ for $n$ greater than some $n_1$.
For $n \geq k n_1$, let $q$ be such that $qk \leq n < (q+1)k$. We have:

$$ (1+x)^n \geq ((1+x)^q)^k > (k(q+1))^k > n^k $$

Here we have: $a^n > n^k$ for all $a>1$, $k \geq 0$, and sufficiently large integers $n$, which I think already goes a little further than the original question ($2^n > n^k$). Just in case someone is interested in "how elementary can be the proof that $a^x$ eventually exceeds any polynomial" (i.e., extending to any polynomial, and to real numbers), here it is.

Step 4: Given $a > 1$ and a polynomial $f$, let $k$ be the degree of $f$, $t$ the number of terms, and $M$ a bound for its coefficients, so that every coefficient of $f$ is between $M$ and $-M$. For large enough $n$, $a^n > n^{k+1} > Mtn^k \geq |f(n)|$.

Next: real numbers.

Step 5: In particular $a^n > (n+1)^k$ eventually. For sufficiently large $x$ we have

$$a^{x} \geq a^{\lfloor x \rfloor} > (\lceil x \rceil)^k \geq x^k $$

Finally we repeat the maneuver in step 4 to get $a^x > f(x)$ for all $a>1$, polynomials $f$, and sufficiently large $x$.

Once again, this answer has only aimed at the "completely elementary" part of the original question and in no way purports to be "from the book". I also make no suggestion about use of this presentation in instruction.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the feedback. I think I clarified it (and cleaned up in general and extended a little).

Comment: Ah shoot, step 5 has a bug. What I should have said is: $a^n > n^{k+1} > Mtn^k > |f(n)|$ for sufficiently large $n$, i.e., $\geq n_0$ and $>Mt$. It's actually simpler than what I wrote (which is wrong because it gives $>Mt n_1^k$, not $Mt n^k$). I don't want to keep editing this answer over and over, though.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457785/most-elementary-proof-showing-that-exponential-growth-wins-against-polynomial-gr#comment1186106_457801), it's on the front page already, and another edit now will only put it on the front page about half an hour longer than if you didn't, so no need to be shy, I think!

Comment: This whole approach was a lot more finicky than I realized. I think it's all correct now.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my response to the original request for a combinatorial proof (although the proof in Zach Teitler's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/457801) is one of my favourites).

Let $[n]^k$ be the language of $k$-letter words over the $n$-letter alphabet $[n] = \{ 0, \dots, n-1 \}$. Let $[2]^n$ be the language of $n$-letter words over the two-letter alphabet $[2] = \{ 0, 1 \}$. Of course $|[n]^k| = n^k$ and $|[2]^n| = 2^n$. Fixing $k$, we need an injective coding from $[n]^k$ into $[2]^n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Let $u = u_0 \dots u_{k-1} \in [n]^k$ be our input, where each $u_i \in [n]$. We want to code $u$ to $w \in [2]^{n}$. The idea is to write $w = v_{\text{positions}} v_{\text{symbols}}$, where $v_{\text{positions}} \in [2]^{k(k+1)}$ and $v_{\text{symbols}} \in [2]^{n-k(k+1)}$. At most $k$ of the $n$ available symbols appear in $u$. We use $v_{\text{positions}}$ to encode the (at most $k$) sets of positions in $u$ at which those (at most $k$) symbols appear, and we use $v_{\text{symbols}}$ to encode *which* symbols appear at those sets of positions.

The details are as follows. They are easy to present in picture form but I think it's worthwhile (and fun) to spell them out.

---

As noted above, at most $k$ of the $n$ symbols in $[n]$ are used in $u$. To each $j \in [n]$, we can associate the subset $A_j = \{ i \in [k] \, | \, u_i = j   \}$. Let $j_0 < j_1 < \cdots < j_{m-1}$ be the set of $j$ such that $A_j$ is nonempty, noting that $m \leq k$.

For each $0 \leq \ell \leq m-1$, let $v_{\ell}$ be the $k$-letter word over $[2]$ giving the indicator function of $A_{j_{\ell}}$, i.e. $(v_{\ell})_{i'} = 1$ if $i' \in A_{j_{\ell}}$ and $0$ otherwise. We need $v_{\text{positions}}$ to have length exactly $k(k+1)$, so if in fact $m < k$, then for $m \leq \ell \leq k-1$ let $v_{\ell} = 0^k$.

So far we have $k$ blocks of length $k$. For $n$ sufficiently large, the following algorithm successfully defines a unique special index $0 \leq \ell^* \leq m$:

- If $j_0 > k(k+1) - 1$: set $\ell^* = 0$ and terminate the algorithm.
- For each $1 \leq \ell \leq m-1$: If $j_{\ell} - j_{\ell-1} > k(k+1)$ then set $\ell^* = \ell$ and terminate the algorithm.
- Set $\ell^* = m$.

Note that if $\ell^* = m$, then $j_{m-1} < n - k(k+1) - 1$. For $0 \leq \ell \leq k-1$, let $a_{\ell} = 1$ if $\ell = \ell^*$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $v_{\text{positions}} = a_0 v_0 a_1 v_1 \dots a_{k-1} v_{k-1}$.

Now, the naive way to define $v_{\text{symbols}}$ is as the word giving the indicator function of the set $\{ j_0, \dots, j_{m-1}  \}$, i.e. $(v_{\text{symbols}})_j = 1$ if $A_j \neq \emptyset$ and $0$ otherwise. Call that naive choice $v'_{\text{symbols}}$.

The trouble is that $v'_{\text{symbols}}$ has length $n$, and we have already reserved a block of length $k(k+1)$ for $v_{\text{positions}}$, so we need to compress $v'_{\text{symbols}}$ a bit. However, if $n$ is sufficiently large, then by pigeonhole, as noted before the algorithm above, $v'_{\text{symbols}}$ contains at least one block of $0$'s of length at least $k(k+1)$: from $0$ to $j_0 - 1$ if $\ell^* = 0$; from $j_{\ell^*-1}$ to $j_{\ell^*}-1$ if $1 \leq \ell^* \leq m-1$; or from $\ell^*$ to $n-1$ if $\ell^* = m$. Choose the block of $0$'s indicated by $\ell^*$ and shorten it by $k(k+1)$ to obtain $v_{\text{symbols}}$. This completes the construction of $w$.

To recover $u$ from $w$: break $w$ into $v_{\text{positions}}$ $v_{\text{symbols}}$, which is unambiguous since their lengths are fixed. Look at the $a_{\ell}$'s in $v_{\text{positions}}$ to determine $\ell^*$ and thus to decide which block of $0$'s in $v_{\text{symbols}}$ to extend by $k(k+1)$ more $0's$, thus recovering $v'_{\text{symbols}}$. Look through $v'_{\text{symbols}}$ to find which symbols $j \in [n]$ were used in $u$. Where $j = j_{\ell}$, place symbol $j \in [n]$ at all the positions $i \in [k]$ where $v_{\ell} = 1$.

Comment: Nice (and thanks for the compliment to my answer). I think in the sentence starting "The trouble is that...", the length of $v'$ is not $2^n$, but rather $n$, right? Also: I guess, without the compression, we get a simple proof that $n^k \leq 2^{n + k(k+1)}$?

Comment: Thanks, corrected! And yes, that's right, so if you're comfortable arguing from $n^k \leq C_k 2^n$ down to $n^k < 2^n$, then you don't need the compression, but it's a fun trick and it felt in the spirit of the question.

Comment: This answer doesn't just prove the inequality, it actually provides an embedding $[n]^k \to 2^{[n]}$ as the question asked for.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a proof with no limits, no logarithms, and no "sufficiently large".

Let $n=4^k$. We're trying to prove that

$$ 2^{4^k} > (4^k)^k.$$

Using the properties of the exponential (which can be proven with an elementary combinatorial argument), this is equivalent to proving that

$$ 2^{4^k} > 2^{2k^2}.$$

Next, note that $2^x$ is monotonically increasing, so this is equivalent to proving that

$$4^k > 2k^2.$$

This, we'll prove via induction. As a base case, for $k=1$, we have $4>2$.

Inductively, assume that statement holds for $k$. Note that $4\ge ((k+1)/k)^2$ for all $k\ge 1$. Multiplying the two inequalities, we have

$$ 4^k \cdot 4 > 2k^2 ((k+1)/k)^2$$
$$4^{k+1} \ge 2(k+1)^2.$$

That proves the induction and completes the proof.

---

This proof could be made fully combinatorial by replacing every inequality with an injective mapping between strings in some alphabets, and building up from the $4^k > 2k^2$ mapping to the $2^{4^k} > (4^k)^k$ mapping.

In particular, here's an explicit $2^{2k-1} > k^2$ mapping:

We want to uniquely map from length 2 strings, where the charcters are $k$-ary, to length $2k-1$ binary strings.

Let the length 2 string be $xy$. Put a 1 in the $x$th position and in the $k+y$th position. Fill all other positions with $0$s. If $y=k$, just omit the second 1 - we can still infer it.

Answer (score 5):

I will be far more concrete than other answerers:

Suppose you increment $x$ from $1\text{ zillion}$ to $(1\text{ zillion}) + 1.$ Then $2^x$ gets twice as big, whereas $x^n$ grows by an amount that, although huge, is microscopic compared to the immense size of $(\text{1 zillion})^n.$

I would try to ascertain that the student understands that that is the central idea before addressing the question of just how we know that that is true.

Even students who get straight $\text{“A}{+}\text{”s}$ in algbera and are magnificently adept at all a techniques in algebra that students are asked to master usually do not understand anything by means of algebra. For example, suppose such a student claims to know that $1+\prod_{p\in S} p$ fails to be divisible by any of the members of $S,$ and they demonstrate that they know all the steps in a proof of that fact, and they understand that proving that fact is the purpose of those steps. Then you say $1+(2\times3\times7) =43$ cannot be divisible by $7$ since the next number after $42$ that is divisible by $7$ is $42+7$ and the last one before that that is divisible by $7$ is $42-7,$ and for the same reason, $1+(2\times3\times7)$ cannot be divisible by $2$ or by $3,$ and they say they never understood that before. I've seen this happen hundreds of times (although only a few times with a proof of *this particular* proposition). The fact that the point of the algebra was to bring them to the point of understanding that which they later came to understand only via concrete examples like this is simply not present in their minds at all.

Comment: This is concrete about teaching advice but not so concrete about how to actually prove the statement.

Comment: Math is about ideas and techniques. Only techniques can be teached. Working out the underlying ideas is painfully slow since mathematical ideas are difficult to transmit. (I try often and fail always.)

Comment: @RolandBacher : You will always fail to teach ideas if your students are there to satisfy a requirement or to get an impressive grade. You will also always fail to teach ideas if your students think mathematics consists of technical skills. Conventional schooling encourages students to be there to satisfy a requirement or get an impressive grade, and does not encourage them to find out that learning mathematics does not consist of learning techniques. Conventional schooling is malpractice.

Comment: @ZachTeitler : It would be wrong to get concrete about that before the student understands what I said in the first paragraph.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Pedagogy works only for students who do not need it. (I do not remember the author and the exact wording of this lovely quotation.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy While your thoughts on teaching are interesting, the question asked for a proof of a statement.

Comment: @RolandBacher "But the power of instruction is seldom of much efficacy, except in those happy dispositions where it is almost superfluous." Edward Gibbon.

Comment: @RolandBacher : Therefore one should only teach those who do not need it. Obviously. To do otherwise is unethical.

Comment: @RolandBacher : Pedagogy for those who do not need it is not superfluous. On the contrary, they need it (in a somewhat different sense of the word "need").

Comment: @GHfromMO $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$

Comment: Making millions of students who have straight $\text{“A}{+}\text{”s}$ is the prerequisites to calculus but have understood none of it is malpractice. And it is almost universal. Some administrators like it that way because such students bring in money. Such administrators are prostitutes.

Comment: I just helped with identifying the original quote...

Comment: @GHfromMO : I certainly didn't mean to suggest that you were responsible for the content of the quote.

Comment: @ZachTeitler : You seem to suggest that I'm not giving a proof of the statement. I omitted algebraic details. Central to what I'm saying is that the omission of algebraic details at that point in the argument is important, and probably required by reasonable norms of logic. But that kind of logic is not yet well developed.

Comment: I hope that I am not the only one who finds this not only a property of pre-college or undergraduate students.  I can't count the number of times I have thought I understood some general concept, only to be astonished by a special case of it that's concrete enough for me to think about, well, concretely.  Perhaps this indicates just that I think like an undergraduate.

Comment: @LSpice : It indicates that you think like a human. The way algebra is taught to graduate students is, just like the way of teaching algebra to 8th-graders, conceals everything about how the subject fits into mathematics and into the cosmos as a whole, since it is considered necessary not to tell people the basic facts of life in the cosmos as a whole until that have spent 20 years mastering the technical prerequisites. Contrast the way Clifford algebras are taught in graduate algebra courses (they're a quotient algebra of a tensor algbebra by$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$an ideal generated by squares) with the way they're taught in physics courses (they have something to do with geometry and with symmetric bilinear forms). $\qquad$

Comment: @LSpice : There is something entitled to be dignified with the epithet of an Ideology that says it is necessary and morally obligatory to arrange the whole math curriculum from kindergarten through Ph.D.-level courses and beyond in a way that says you're not allowed to learn a subject until you have ALL of the technical skills that can be used in that subject. Thus students are told about all sorts of different kinds of LIMITS before they see the definition of "derivative". Look at the result: the general public thinks mathematics consists of application of memorized$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$algorithms whose purpose is unknown (e.g. you must learn partial fractions before you are permitted to know anything at all about calculus). Those misconceptions held be a broad public are OBVIOUSLY the result of that way of organizing math curriculums.

Comment: I agree with you that it is more important for beginning high-level mathematical activity to have an intuitive grasp of the objects being manipulated than to know the formal definitions (which come later, when one is proving the correctness of one's intuitions); but I disagree with what seems to be the implicit claim that automatically algebra is unintuitive, and geometry more intuitive.  Certainly I understand algebraic geometry better by thinking of it as algebra than as geometry.  (But, to be fair, I don't understand algebraic geometry very well.)

Comment: @LSpice : I wasn't saying algebra less intuitive than geometry. I was saying the curriculum requires you know what all techniques that can be applied in an area of study before you find out that that area of study exists. And that is OBVIOUSLY, by a mechanism functioning openly for all to see, causing the popular misconceptions about what mathematics is.

Comment: You can even be more specific about (1 zillion + 1)${}^n$, using $(x+1)^n = x^n + n x^{n-1} + (\text{smaller powers of }x)$

Comment: @Stef : Clearly you can be a lot more specific about everything. What you suggest makes it necessary to explain why $nx^{n-1} + \text{smaller powers}$ is tiny compared to $x^n.$ That of course must be done, but first the point mentioned in the second paragraph of my answer should be understood. I wouldn't bother with the rest with a student who hasn't understood what is being said there.

Answer (score 5):

The following argument is not elementary, but nice and simple, so I feel like sharing.

First observe that the function $x/\log x$ is increasing for $x>4$, whence it exceeds $4/\log 4$ for $x>4$. This is equivalent to $4^x>x^4$ for $x>4$. Taking the square-root of both sides, we see that $2^x>x^2$ for $x>4$. Now assume that $2^{n/k}>\max(16,k^2)$. Then $n/k>4$ and $2^{n/k}>k^2$. Applying our initial observation to $x=n/k$, it also follows that $2^{n/k}>n^2/k^2$. Hence in fact $2^{n/k}$ exceeds the geometric mean of $k^2$ and $n^2/k^2$, which is $n$. In other words, $2^n>n^k$.

Comment: I thought the OP said they didn't want to use logs anywhere in the proof?

Comment: @HollisWilliams Yes, this proof is not the kind the OP wanted. I just wanted to emphasize that a clean (and almost optimal) lower bound on $n$ can be obtained in a simple way. For example, for $k\geq 4$, the lower bound $2^n>k^{2k}$ implies $2^n>n^k$. In contrast, the binomial coefficient argument requires $n>2^k(k+1)!$ to guarantee $2^n>n^k$. There is a huge difference between $2^n>k^{2k}$ and $n>2^k(k+1)!$.

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)\gg g(x)$ if $f'(x)\gg g'(x)$. The derivatives of an exponential are exponential, but the derivatives of any polynomial are eventually $0$. So for $f(x)=2^x$ and $g(x)=x^k$, the fact that $f^{(k+1)}(x)\gg 0=g^{(k+1)}(x)$ gives the desired conclusion.

Comment: If the students want a formal proof and are uncomfortable with $\gg$, this reasoning can be turned into a proof by induction, using the fact that if $f(a) \geq g(a)$ and $\forall x \geq a,\, f'(x) \geq g'(x)$, then $\forall x \geq a,\, f(x) \geq g(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let's apply a simple inequality:

**Theorem 0**    Let real variables satisfy condition
$\ 0<D<b<a.\ $ Then

$$ \frac ab\ <\ \frac{a-D}{b-D}. $$

---

Thus, we see that (for $n>1$):

$$ \frac{n^k}{(n-1)^k}\ <
  \,\ \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}{\prod_{j=1}^k(n-j)}\ =\ \frac n{n-k} $$

hence

$$ \frac{n^k}{(n-1)^k}\ <\ \frac 32\qquad \text{whenever}
   \quad n\ge 3\cdot k. $$

It follows that for $\ n > 3\cdot k$,

$$ n^k\,\ <\,\ (3\cdot k)^k\,\cdot\ \left(\frac32\right)^{n-3\cdot k} $$

$$ =\ (3\cdot k)^k\,\cdot\ \left(\frac23\right)^{3\cdot k}\, \cdot
\, \left(\frac32\right)^n\,\ =\,\ C_k\cdot \left(\frac32\right)^n $$
for
$$ C_k\ :=\ (3\cdot k)^k\,\cdot\ \left(\frac23\right)^{3\cdot k}. $$

Finally,

$$ \frac {n^k}{2^n}\,\ <\,\ C_k\cdot\left(\frac34\right)^n\   $$

so that
$$ \lim_{n=\infty} \frac {n^k}{2^n}\ =\ 0. $$

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to move to real analysis, you can show by an elementary variational argument that $f~:~x\geq 2k+2 ~~\longmapsto ~~x^{(k+1)} 2^{-x}$ is decreasing, since the derivative is $(k+1-x\ln 2)\frac{f(x)}{x}$, thus bounded from above by $f(2k+2)$. You don't get the exponential decay, though, and you need to know that $2^x=\exp(x\ln 2)$ and $\ln (2) > 1/2$.

Comment: I think that you need that exponential functions majors polynomial functions to compute the derivative of exponential functions.

Comment: @Z.M Yes, obviously the argument is less elementary if one wishes to establish the whole real analysis/calculus beforehand ;)  I knew my answer was not spot-on, but it's nonetheless calculus-elementary once you know that $ \exp'=\exp $. Regarding taking derivative of $\exp$, I guess it all depends on how you build the exponential. If you take it as the limit of $(1+x/n)^n$, you don't need to control the growth of exponentials wrt polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

Let $0<q<1$ and $k \geq 1$. Pick $ \epsilon >0$ with $r:= q(1+\epsilon) <1$. By the Bernoulli inequality
$$0 \leq q^n n^k = \frac{n}{(1+\epsilon)^n}(n^{k-1}r^n)\leq\frac{n}{1+n\epsilon}(n^{k-1}r^n)\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} (n^{k-1}r^n).$$
By induction on $k$, the second factor tends to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

By the binomial theorem
$$
2^{\frac{n}{k}} =(1+\sqrt[k]{2}-1)^n  > \binom{n}{2}(\sqrt[k]{2}-1) 
$$
Now, for $n$ large enough (this can be calculated explicitely) we have
$$
\binom{n}{2}(\sqrt[k]{2}-1) >n 
$$

Answer (score 2):

For $k\ge1  $ and $$n\ge 4k^2$$ (that is $\frac{2k}{\sqrt n}\le 1$) set $x_1=\dots=x_{2k}=\sqrt n$ and $x_{2k+1}=\dots=x_n=1$. The arithmetic mean of these $n$ numbers is $\frac{ 2k\sqrt n +n-2k}n\le \frac{2k}{\sqrt n}+1\le2$, the geometric mean is $n^{k/n}$ and the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality gives $$2^n\ge n^k.$$

Comment: (The A-G mean inequality has several elementary proofs, e.g. the one by Cauchy)

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $2^x > kx$ for all large $x$, because then we can take the $k$th power of both sides: $2^{kx} > (kx)^k$ for all large $n = kx$.

At least for $x$ an integer, $2^x > kx$ is easy to prove by induction on $x$. We can get the base case by noting that if $m \ge 3$ then $2m < 2^m$ and hence $(2m)^2 < (2^m)^2 = 2^{2m}$; thus $2^k > k^2$ for $k \ge 6$, and we can take $x=k$ as the base case for $k\ge 6$.

Comment: But the OP asks for  “there exists $n>0$ such that for all $m\ge n$ one has $2^m>m^k$”

Comment: @PietroMajer Ah, I see. I have edited the argument to address this, though admittedly it's not very elegant when $x$  is a multiple of $1/k$ but not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: Assume $\Delta f(x) > \varepsilon > 0$ for all $x$ greater than some constant. Then $f(x) > \varepsilon’ > 0$ for some $\varepsilon'$ and all $x$ greater than some constant.

Proof: From the condition $\Delta f(x) > \varepsilon > 0$, for any $K$, there exists an $N$ such that, for all $n \ge N$, $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \Delta f(x) = f(n+1) - f(0) > K$. Choose $K$ such that $K+f(0)>0$, and the conclusion follows.

Next, note that $\Delta^n2^x = 2^x$ for all $n$ and that there exist a $p$ such that $\Delta^p g(x) = 0$ for $g$ any polynomial. This implies that $\Delta^p(2^x - g(x))=2^x$. Applying the lemma gives that
$$
2^x > g(x)
$$
for any polynomial $g(x)$ and $x$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

First establish the simplest case $2^{m} > m^{2}$ for $m > 4$, for example by induction: the inequality holds for $m = 5$ and $2^{m+1} = 2 \cdot 2^m > 2 m^2 = m^2 + m^2 > m^2 + 2m + 1 = (m+1)^2$, since $m^2 > 3m > 2m+1$ for $m \geq 5$.

Next, given $k > 1$, show that there are arbitrarily large $n$ for which $2^n > n^k$. It suffices to take $n := 2^{ak}$ for $ak > 5$, since $2^{n} = 2^{(2^{ak})} > 2^{((ak)^2)} = n^{ak} > n^k$.

Finally, if $n$ is large enough, then $(n+1)^{k} / n^{k} = (1+\frac{1}{n})^{k} < 2$, while $2^{n+1} / 2^{n} = 2$, so $2^n > n^k$ implies $2^{n+1} > (n+1)^k$. The required inequality therefore holds for all large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For some fixed positive integer $k$, let $n^k < 2^n < n^{k+1}$

Now if we go from $n$ to $n+1$ and take ratios we get:
$\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n} = 2 > \frac{(n+1)^{k+1}}{n^{k+1}}= \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{k+1} = 1$ for large $n$ and fixed $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest considering instead the stronger statement that $n^k/2^n \to 0$. (This would of course necessitate an explanation of what it means for a function to converge to zero as the argument tends to infinity.) Since $n^k/2^n \to 0$ implies $n^{2k}/2^n \to 0$ by squaring, we may reduce to $k=1$.

We thus have to show that $n/2^n \to 0$. We can represent this visually by comparing $n=\underbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}_{\textrm{$n$ summands}}$ to $2^n=\underbrace{2 \times 2 \times \ldots \times 2}_{\textrm{$n$ factors}}$. Now the first expression is always less than the first, and it is intuitively completely obvious that the ratio between the two can be increased indefinitely, since one makes a number increase faster by repeatedly multiplying by $2$ than by repeatedly adding $1$. This should be a convincing argument for anyone who's played around with a calculator.

In fact, I think I would leave it at that. It's not a "proof", of course, but all the same, it would convince most people that the statement must be true (and hence that a proof must exist).

Of course, finishing the proof is not hard either, since $\frac{n+1}{n}$ decreases monotonically (and is equal to $3/2$ at $n=2$) whereas $\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}=2$.

In fact since $\frac{n+1}{n} \to 1$ this argument proves that the ratio between the two expression is $> C_{\epsilon} 2^{n(1-\epsilon)}$ for any $\epsilon>0$, implying $n < C_{\epsilon}^{-1} 2^{\epsilon n}$. From this, you easily get the statement for general $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$n \ge k^2 \implies n \ge k \sqrt{n} \implies 2^{n} \ge 2^{k \sqrt{n}}$. And $\sqrt{n} \ge \log_2(n)$ for large enough $n$ so $2^{k \sqrt{n}} \ge 2^{k \log_2(n)} = n^k$.

Comment: Isn't "And $\sqrt{n} \geq \log_2(n)$ a particular case of the claim you are trying to prove?

Comment: It's arguably simpler since there is no $k$ now :)